# where can I find the source code of function "setcon" in libselinux?

Tags: selinux

I'm trying to figure out how Selinux works, and I see a function named `setcon` at several places, which is declared in `selinux/selinux.h` and there is a man page entry for it. However I can't find the implementation(i.e. source code) of this function in the source code of libselinux. Anyone could tell me where the source code of setcon is? Thanks a lot.

```c
/* Set the current security context to con.
   Note that use of this function requires that the entire application
   be trusted to maintain any desired separation between the old and new
   security contexts, unlike exec-based transitions performed via setexeccon.
   When possible, decompose your application and use setexeccon()+execve()
   instead. Note that the application may lose access to its open descriptors
   as a result of a setcon() unless policy allows it to use descriptors opened
   by the old context. */
extern int setcon(const char * con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out this by myself. Actually, the function "setcon" is defined at  `/libselinux/src/proattr.c` using several macros.

```c
#define setselfattr_def(fn, attr) \
int set##fn(const char * c) \
{ \
    return setprocattrcon(c, 0, #attr); \
}

#define all_selfattr_def(fn, attr) \
  getselfattr_def(fn, attr)  \
  setselfattr_def(fn, attr)

all_selfattr_def(con, current)
```

As we can see from above, the real function is "setprocattrcon", which is also defined at the same source file.